# Pass boolean argument to qdbus

Tags: shell-script, d-bus

I'm trying to use qdbus instead of dbus-send for brevity, but I can't figure out, how to send a boolean argument. It's getting detected as "s".

I'm trying to control an mpris bus and setting shuffle on it, and I tried passing it as true, 1, boolean:true, boolean:1, yes, on, and so on, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.